# Changing labelfield on Flex ToggleButtonBar loses CSS style

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

As the title describes, changing the labelField on a Flex ToggleButtonBar causes all styles to disappear. It only re-appears after clicking on a button again. Can someone provide a fix?

Note I'm using Flex 3.6. You can see the behaviour with the code below. Click on either button to change the label field, and in the bar the style of the selected button disappears:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
            layout="vertical">

<mx:Style>

    .myStyle 
    {   
        buttonStyleName: "tabStyle";
        selectedButtonTextStyleName: "tabTextSelected";
    }

    .tabStyle 
    {   
        color: #000000;
    }

    .tabTextSelected
    {
        color: #FF0000;
    }   

</mx:Style>

<mx:ToggleButtonBar id="myToggleButtonBar" styleName="myStyle"
                    labelField="title0">

    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:Object title0="Apple" title1="Pomme" />
        <mx:Object title0="Cherry" title1="Cerise" /> 
    </mx:dataProvider>

</mx:ToggleButtonBar>

<mx:Button label="title0" click="{myToggleButtonBar.labelField = 'title0' }" /> 
<mx:Button label="title1" click="{myToggleButtonBar.labelField = 'title1' }" /> 

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here is not that the styles are being lost, it's that when you change the `labelField` the `ToggleButtonBar` is resetting it's `selectedIndex` property (resetting the selected tab). This seems like a fair thing for it to be doing when you change something like the `dataProvider` of the tab (or something that affects how the label is extracted from the `dataProvider`).

Solution: Before you change the `labelField`, get the `selectedIndex` and re-set it on the `ToggleButtonBar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                layout="vertical">

    <mx:Style>

        .myStyle 
        {   
            buttonStyleName: "tabStyle";
            selectedButtonTextStyleName: "tabTextSelected";
        }

        .tabStyle 
        {   
            color: #000000;
        }

        .tabTextSelected
        {
            color: #FF0000;
        }

    </mx:Style>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function toggleLabelField():void
            {
                var currentLabelField:String = myToggleButtonBar.labelField;
                var currentTab:int = myToggleButtonBar.selectedIndex;
                trace("selectedIndex before changing labelField: " + currentTab);
                var newLabelField:String = currentLabelField == 'title0' ? 'title1' : 'title0';
                myToggleButtonBar.labelField = newLabelField;
                trace("selectedIndex after changing labelField: " + myToggleButtonBar.selectedIndex);
                myToggleButtonBar.selectedIndex = currentTab;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:ToggleButtonBar id="myToggleButtonBar" styleName="myStyle"
                        labelField="title0">

        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:Object title0="Apple" title1="Pomme" />
            <mx:Object title0="Cherry" title1="Cerise" /> 
        </mx:dataProvider>

    </mx:ToggleButtonBar>

    <mx:Button label="title0" click="{myToggleButtonBar.labelField = 'title0' }" /> 
    <mx:Button label="title1" click="{myToggleButtonBar.labelField = 'title1' }" />
    <mx:Button label="toggle it" click="toggleLabelField()" />

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: That's it... thanks! But I would add that I don't see that as expected behaviour since it's not actually changing the dataProvider but a view on it (the label)